# Python Spyder : How to comment a specific section of code?

Tags: python, comments, spyder

This is an easy one :

I work with Spyder 3.7 IDE and i would like to comment only the part between the two stars ** in the following code to permit me to desactivate the concatenation of the df "dftwo" in agg :

```
agg = pd.concat([dfOne, **dfTwo,** dfThree])
```

I remember we had the following syntax in SAS but it does not work here :

```
agg = pd.concat([dfOne, /*dfTwo,*/ dfThree])
```

I also tried few combinations with ''' or # but it does not comment the specific code...

```
agg = pd.concat([dfOne, '''dfTwo,''' dfThree)]
  File "<ipython-input-107-a3c09b662840>", line 1
    agg = pd.concat([dfOne, '''dfTwo,''' dfThree)]
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Spyder, Python does not support inline comments.

You can do:

```py
agg = pd.concat([
    dfOne,
    # dfTwo,
    dfThree
)]
```

Or maybe:

```py
agg = pd.concat([df[i] for i in permitted_dfs])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i haven't thought about that easy trick !